# All the JBehave steps are marked as PENDING when executing them in SerenityBDD

Tags: annotations, pojo, jbehave, serenity-bdd, scenarios

I'm trying to execute a very simple story with login functionality in Serenity BDD and JBehave framework. But, all my steps are marked as PENDING and skipped.  Please help me understand what is really going wrong with my code.

I have made sure that the steps in my Story file and Step file are exactly matching each other and there are no differences in terms of white spaces or tab characters.

**Story File**

```
Story: Application Login

Narrative:
As an user, I want to successfully login into the application upon providing valid credential

Scenario:  Login with valid credential
Given Launch the application
When Input the credential
Then Login to the application
```

**Step Class**

```java
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;
import tests.LoginTest;

public class LoginSteps {

    @Steps
    LoginTest usr;

    @Given("Launch the application")
    public void launchApp() {
        usr.beforeSuite();
        usr.launchApplication();
    }

    @When("Input the credential")
    public void enterCredential() {
        usr.submitLoginForm();
    }

    @Then("Login to the application")
    public void loginApp() {
        usr.loginCheck();
        usr.afterSuite();
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```java
package suite;

import net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStory;

public class Login extends SerenityStory {

}
```

**POM.XML**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.selenium.bdd.serenity</groupId>
<artifactId>seleniumBDDSerenity</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>seleniumBDDSerentity</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.33</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
        <version>1.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/suite/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.33</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Log**

```
(BeforeStories)

Running story stories/authentication/Login.story
Application Login
(stories/authentication/Login.story)
Using timeout for story Login.story of 300 secs.

Scenario: Login with valid credential
Given Launch the application (PENDING)
When Input the credential (PENDING)
Then Login to the application (PENDING)

@Given("Launch the application")
@Pending
public void givenLaunchTheApplication() {
  // PENDING
}

@When("Input the credential")
@Pending
public void whenInputTheCredential() {
  // PENDING
}

@Then("Login to the application")
@Pending
public void thenLoginToTheApplication() {
  // PENDING
}

(AfterStories)
```

Comment: I don't use Serenity with my JBehave, but it looks like something is making it act sort of like Cucumber where if it can't find the steps, it's either suggesting the steps, or it's created a steps file (based on your output) somewhere with default method names all empty (pending) and it's using that steps file instead of your steps file.  That's the kind of stub file that JBehave creates with my plug-in when I tell it to generate steps from the story file.

Comment: @BillHileman But this is how most of the Jbehave examples are outlined online and it works without any issues for them. Please let me know if you have any suggestions to resolve it.

Comment: I think that you have a java steps file somewhere that your runtime is finding and using, and it's not the one you wrote and posted.  Look in your project tree for a source file that you can't account for.  There's almost certainly one that contains the exact code you have in the log section you posted.  Also, again because I don't use Serenity, I don't know if this applies or not, but I have to have a testrunner class.  You don't show anything resembling a testrunner.

Comment: Thanks. I have extended my Test Class  to SerenityStory which in turn extended to JUnitStories through which it identifies my Story file and executes it. Also, I have just one step file in my project that I mentioned here. Not sure why it is trying refer the default methods it creates during run time instead of matching step files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I fixed it. Move runner class to same folder where LoginSteps is placed.